# Too Many Redirect Error while using a custom Spring Security Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-filter

I am getting too many redirects while trying to apply a filter to check a custom UserDetails to make sure a user goes through a process while logging in. Here is what I have for my config and Filter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /*
     * @Autowired public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
     * throws Exception {
     * auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles(
     * "ADMIN", "USER").and().withUser("user") .password("user").roles("USER");
     * }
     */

    @Autowired
    MySuccessHandler mySuccessHandler;

    /*
     * @Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     * web.ignoring() // Spring Security should completely ignore URLs starting
     * with /resources/ .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**"); }
     */

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(mySuccessHandler).permitAll().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Here is my Filter:

```
    public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        try {
            SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");

                MyUser myUser = (MyUser) sci.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                if (myUser.isFirstLogin()) {
                    resp.sendRedirect("/hub/initial/landing");
                }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Any help on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated. I have tried commenting out my redirect in my successHandler and that did not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean urlRequest = passwordURL.equals(req.getRequestURI());

        MyUser myUser = (MyUser) sci.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (myUser.isFirstLogin()) {
            if (urlRequest) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else
                res.sendRedirect(passwordURL);
        }
```

This solved the issue for me.